# How to setup Cloudfront with multiple distributions (one domain and one bucket)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to setup my cdn to serve resources, which are split in between my S3 bucket and my app server. I have a behaviors set like below :

```
Precedence : 0     Path Pattern : /ws/*.js -> serve from S3 bucket folder /ws
Precedence : 1     Path Pattern : /*.js -> serve from app server
```

Requests to `http://XXXX.cloudfront.net/test.js` works properly, but when i try to load a file in the bucket as `http://XXXX.cloudfront.net/ws/test-bucket.js` it gives me AccessDenied . I have already set the permissions properly on the bucket and loading it directly from the s3 url works properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.